# Spring boot REST token authorization and authentication best practices

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

What is the best practise for authorization and authentication of users in REST spring boot?

I am building web app with standard pages + REST API for mobile. I looked at many articles about Spring security and basically most of them goes with some sort of fitler approach that will allow or block REST calls. In my case, however, I have some auth logic based on who the user is. For example, there is a `/update` API that updates user  information, and user can update himself, but cannot update other person. 
Initially I thought to use next auth schema:

- User calls auth API and pass name/password or cookie
- System generates short life token, saves in it's database.
- User get this token, updates his cookie (so JS in web application can read and use it)
- When REST call is being make cookies are passed. At Controller, token is extracted, checked for expiration, query is done to database to validate token and get user id.
- Based on user id, REST will be permited or blocked.

Is this the right approach to implement? I have a pretty big mess in my head after reading articles about spring boot security. 
At least: session auth will not work for me (REST is stateless). I want to make auth for mobile device without storing login/password there.

Does it make sense to pass this token in the REST body itself? What in case of GET method?

Many thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Just curious, but what do you think the advantage is of token state stored in a database over authentication state stored in the session (which is much easier to work with since you don't have to deal with persistence at all)?

Comment: Rest is stateless. There are no session. And second: in both cases (even with session), you will need to store session values somewhere. Some use redis, I want persistense.

Comment: Security needs state. And TCP is stateful. So if you want to use either of those you are not going to be stateless. It's a pointless discussion to have in comments on stackoverflow, but I think you should re-evaluate your priorities (or redefine "stateless").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you find a solution to your problem?

I have answered this problem elsewhere, if you are sure you won't want to open up the API to other developers/clients in the future (if you do then you should look at OAuth) then a simple token based solution will work.

Something basically along the lines of this:

- Setup a standard html login page, that you can use for user login to the app
- setup spring security to return a cookie on sucessful login with an authentication token
- in your mobile app, embed a WebView (or equivalent) and load this login form - allow the user to login via that webview, on response grab the cookie and store the token (as mobile is generally single user, you can keep that pretty long to save mobile users having to keep logging in)
- Add a security filter to the the REST API to authenticate against the token (from the mobile app pass the token in the header for example) - then you will be able to use normal spring authentication context for current users etc.

This approach is suggested by Google here: (EDIT: Google seems to have changed the page I originally read to be about using Google+ sign in and OAuth2.0 - I can't see a link to their general Mobile/API docs [so here it is in the web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20130822184827/https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps) :) )

I have also written up my implementation here:

[Overview of the approach using Spring security](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/securing-your-api-for-mobile-access.html)

[The code & details](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/securing-your-mobile-api-spring-security.html)

Although this was really just an experiment/Proof of concept, it might be useful in your thinking.

Comment: REST shouldn't be using cookies. It's stateless. Go for token authorization instead.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie approach seems perfect for the use case. Token can be tied up with user id. Filter can extract cookie and pass user id for example as header to apis - that should take care of GET...